# PIXI: browser sends no cookies with Texture.fromImage()

Tags: javascript, session-cookies, pixi.js

I am trying to use PIXI to create an image-based sprite, thus:

```
var s = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.fromImage("bunny.png"))
```

My server can only locate the correct image file if the request for "bunny.png" arrives with a session cookie. Unfortunately, no cookies are sent (which is evident from server side debugging, and clearly evident in Chrome's developer console).

If I add a simple img tag in the html, I observe (in Chrome's developer console) that cookies are sent and the image is returned without any trouble:

```
<img src="bunny.png">
```

I am using PIXI 3.0.5.

What am I failing to understand? Why would these two bunnies behave so differently?

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.fromImage("bunny.png", false))
```

The default behavior is to pretend that we want to avoid cross-site scripting abuse, so cookies are suppressed. This is how the PIXI tutorials work, apparently (and who cares about cookies in that case?)

If you want the cookies, you must set the `crossdomain` parameter to `false`.

I thought I had tried that already, but evidently I was mistaken! Bunnies everywhere now..